How do I make the tab navigator appear at the bottom of my application's detail pages?
This is my Tab Bar Components file:
    import {Text, TouchableOpacity, View} from "react-native";
    import {AntDesign, Entypo} from '@expo/vector-icons';
    
    export default function TabBarComp({state, descriptors, navigation}) {
        return (
            <View className="flex flex-row justify-between shadow bg-white h-[70] w-full">
                {state.routes.map((route, index) => {
                    const {options} = descriptors[route.key];
                    const label =
                        options.tabBarLabel !== undefined
                            ? options.tabBarLabel
                            : options.title !== undefined
                                ? options.title
                                : route.name;
                    const isFocused = state.index === index;
                    const onPress = () => {
                        const event = navigation.emit({
                            type: 'tabPress',
                            target: route.key,
                        });
                        if (!isFocused && !event.defaultPrevented) {
                            navigation.navigate(route.name);
                        }
                    };
                    const onLongPress = () => {
                        navigation.emit({
                            type: 'tabLongPress',
                            target: route.key,
                        });
                    };
                    return (
                        <TouchableOpacity
                            key={index}
                            className={`flex flex-1 items-center justify-center`}
                            accessibilityRole="button"
                            accessibilityStates={isFocused ? ['selected'] : []}
                            accessibilityLabel={options.tabBarAccessibilityLabel}
                            onPress={onPress}
                            onLongPress={onLongPress}
                        >
                            {route.name === "Home" ? isFocused ? <Entypo name="home" size={30} color="#B79845"/> :
                                <AntDesign name="home" size={24} color="#43525A"/> : null}
                            {route.name === "Activity" ? isFocused ?
                                <AntDesign name="calendar" size={30} color="#B79845"/> :
                                <AntDesign name="calendar" size={24} color="#43525A"/> : null}
                            {route.name === "Announ" ? isFocused ?
                                <AntDesign name="notification" size={30} color="#B79845"/> :
                                <AntDesign name="notification" size={24} color="#43525A"/> : null}
                            {route.name === "General" ? isFocused ? <AntDesign name="book" size={30} color="#B79845"/> :
                                <AntDesign name="book" size={24} color="#43525A"/> : null}
                            {route.name === "More" ? isFocused ? <AntDesign name="appstore-o" size={30} color="#B79845"/> :
                                <AntDesign name="appstore-o" size={24} color="#43525A"/> : null}
                            <Text
                                className={`text-center font-semibold text-[9px] ${isFocused ? "font-black text-secondary" : "text-primary"}`}>
                                {label}
                            </Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    );
                })}
            </View>
        );
    }

How do I make the tab navigator appear at the bottom of my application's detail pages?

You can try the following:

Ensure Correct Placement in Navigation Structure:

Make sure your TabBarComp is used within the Tab.Navigator component of your main navigation configuration.

Style the TabBar to Stay at the Bottom:


position: 'absolute'bottom: 0

Also adjust height, width.
